# ASP.NET FileSystemWatcher Changed Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web, filesystemwatcher

I created a ASP.NET Website with Visual Studio 2010 C#.

My program reads a config file to create some classes and display informations.

The config file is not included in the project (does not appear in the solution explorer). If I modify the file while my application is not running, and run it afterwards, it still reads the old version like it keep it in cache. I have to close Visual Studio for it to accept the changes.

My second problem is related to (if not caused by) my first problem. I am using FileSystemWatcher to see if the config file is modified while the application is running, but the Changed event is never called.

```
private string _configFilePath;
private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Gets the config file in the application's parent directory
    string appPath = this.MapPath("~");
    string[] split = appPath.Split('\\');
    _configFilePath = appPath.Substring(0, appPath.Length - split[split.Length-1].Length);

    Application.Add("watcher", new FileSystemWatcher(_configFilePath.Substring(0, _configFilePath.Length-1), "*.xml"));
    _watcher = (FileSystemWatcher)Application["watcher"];
    _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
    _watcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Changed);

    _configFilePath += "ProductsConfig.xml";

    UpdateDisplay();
}

private void Watcher_Changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDisplay();
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My second problem is related to (if not caused by) my first problem. I
>   am using FileSystemWatcher to see if the config file is modified while
>   the application is running, but the Changed event is never called.

It's never called because at that point the Thread that's servicing the request is already returned to the pool and the request has ended. The `Watcher_Changed` event will never fire.

You need to tackle this in a different manner, remember that HTTP is a "disconnected" protocol, after the request has been served, don't expect any of the page events to fire "automagically" when something happens on the server side that would notify all connected users.

One way to do this is via Ajax. You'd need to constantly "ask" the server whether there's new information or not and update the sections of the page that need to be updated as a result of the change on the server.

Comment: Ok, I will try to change my strategy then. Could I try to do a periodical pooling to check the modified date of the file and refresh if it was modified? Also, why do I have to keep closing my solution (when if I stopped the application) to be able to read the modification in the file?

Comment: @Amaranth `Could I try to do a periodical pooling to check the modified date of the file and refresh if it was modified?` Yes, that's what I am suggesting. If you read the file on every request (or whatever requirement you have), you should be able to pick up the changes w/o restarting the app. The reason it doesn't work now is because you only read the file once.

Comment: I just finished implementing the Ajax timer and the refresh event is fired every 1.5 seconds correctly. It checks the modified time and compares it to the pevious one. If it was modified after, the file is read again.

However, when the file is read again, it's not the new data I receive, but I still read the old file for some reason... Did my application keep the file in cache?

Comment: @Amaranth that's what it looks like... Post the code that reads the file if you can.

Comment: It wasn't working because of my own dumb self...

To refresh the grid, I was calling the instance of my ProductsConfig, which is a singleton, so the file was never read again... The timer fixed the original issue and I modified the ProductsConfig to read when necessary. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Actually, I might have a last question. I notice that the timer was not only calling the tmrTimer_click function, but also the Page_load each time, even if there is nothing to refresh. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Amaranth No, there's no way to prevent that unless you make your ajax request to a web service or an http handler (which is what I would have done to prevent the full page life cycle unnecessarily).

Comment: The page_load is still called, but I was able to prevent the visual effects of the page reloading by placing by grid in an updatepanel with UpdateMode="Conditional", so it doesn't bother me anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here.
1. You never called _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
2. You try to go to the parent folder of your root folder, which might not be allowed.

/ Tibi